# How to make cloned drive bootable with EFI

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, clone

I have an HP All-In-One desktop with a 2TB internal HDD. The partition structure is like this:

```
Partition 1 - EFI System Partition
Partition 4 - (Recovery Partition)
Windows (C:) (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Basic Data Partition)
RECOVERY(D:) (Basic Data Partition)
```

The C: drive only has around 50GB of data.

I installed a 256GB SSD in the available M2 slot. The goal is to migrate the C: drive to the new SSD, and repurpose the HDD as a data disk.

I used [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) to clone the Windows partition to the SSD. It's partition structure looks like this:

```
Windows (F:) (Basic Data Partition)
```

I'm not able to boot from the SSD. In the system BIOS, the SSD is visible as a device however it cannot be selected in the boot order menu. The boot order menu looks like this:

```
UEFI Boot Sources
    OS Boot Manager
        Windows Boot Manager (*HDD ID)*
    USB Hard Drive
    USB Floppy/CD
    ATAPI CD/DVD Drive
    Network Controller
Legacy Boot Sources : Disabled
```

I tried disconnecting the HDD, but then no bootable devices are found.

Why can I not boot from the SSD? Does it need the EFI partition as well, and if so, how can I create it? Can the EFI partition exist on more than one drive? If necessary, I can reclone the drive in a different way but I want it to be bootable.

I would rather not disconnect the HDD again, as opening the machine is quite an endeavour. I've read lots of similar questions and documentation but I'm lacking a clear understanding of EFI and how the EFI partition works across multiple drives.

I would rather not start from scratch with the new drive (new Windows install, etc). It seems it should be possible to create a bootable clone, boot from it and then format the HDD...

Comment: All the partitions are required. You should clone the *disk*, not only the Windows partition.

Comment: Cone the full disk to the new SSD, plus make a backup of the recovery partition. Now delete the recovery partition, extend the Windows partition up to the max minus the size of the recovery partition. And finally restore the recovery partition.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. So both disks will have the EFI partition. Is that correct? Is that's what needed for the drive to be bootable?

Comment: Yes, but only one will be used, I can't predict which one, but you may set your boot disk in the BIOS. As the target disk is smaller than the source disk, the results depend on Macrium Reflect (there are alternative products if it fails).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! Does the partition order matter? Does the EFI partition need to be first on the disk? Basically - can I just go ahead and clone the missing partitions?

Comment: The partition order matters a lot, since partitions are addressed by number.